# Why does a Task appear to be running from one query, but not running from another query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a task `TS_COMBI_REFRESH` that calls a stored procedure `TS_COMBI_REFRESH()`.
I called the task manually by doing `EXECUTE TASK TS_COMBI_REFRESH`.

In this table, it immediately has the execution_status of SUCCESS.

```
select query_id, query_text, execution_status from table(information_schema.query_history())
```

| query_id | query_text | execution_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01aadef8-0000-5dea-0000-070150bda36e | EXECUTE TASK TS_COMBI_REFRESH | SUCCESS |

But in this table, it shows that it is still running.

```
select QUERY_ID, QUERY_TEXT, STATE from table(information_schema.task_history(
    scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('day',-7,current_timestamp()),
    result_limit => 100,
    task_name=>'TS_COMBI_REFRESH'))
order by scheduled_time;
```

| query_id | query_text | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01aadef8-0000-5dea-0000-070150bda372 | call TS_COMBI_REFRESH() | EXECUTING |

Which one is more accurate?

Comment: Note: your query_id are different in your 2 statement outputs.  That means they are different queries.  They are both correctly displaying what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct: `EXECUTE TASK TS_COMBI_REFRESH`
invokes the task  and this statement is finished successfully. The actual task is scheduled(for immediate run) and invoked.

`EXECUTE TASK` does not wait until the run of task actually finishes.

If we look carefully there are two separate queries:

| query_text | execution_status | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EXECUTE TASK TS_COMBI_REFRESH | SUCCESS | task's invocation |
| call TS_COMBI_REFRESH() | EXECUTING | task's payload |

---

[EXECUTE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-task#usage-notes)

> Manually triggers an **asynchronous single run** of a scheduled task (either a standalone task or the root task in a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of tasks) independent of the schedule defined for the task.
>
> Usage notes:
>
> - **While calls to the EXECUTE TASK command are handled synchronously, task runs are asynchronous operations**

Comment: In that case, how can I kill the task? Because when I do 

select system$cancel_query('01aadef8-0000-5dea-0000-070150bda372');

It tells me:
Identified SQL statement is not currently executing.

Even though it is Executing.

Comment: @EeAnnNg When cancelling the query please make sure you have [the right permissions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_cancel_query#usage-notes)  "OWNERSHIP on the user who executed the operation. or OPERATE or OWNERSHIP on the warehouse that is running the operation (if applicable)."

Comment: Found the correct command to cancel a task. SELECT SYSTEM$USER_TASK_CANCEL_ONGOING_EXECUTIONS('TS_COMBI_REFRESH');